# In jenkins what will be my Playbook path ? how to set up Inventory there are 3 option for the same

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, devops, ansible-inventory

I have installed the Jenkins and ansible on my AWS Instance centos 
and am trying to call my ansible playbook  from jenkins ?
I dont know how to set up : what will be my Playbook path ? 
how to set up Inventory there are 3 option for the same (
1. Do not specify Inventory 
2. File or host list
3.Inline content)
Help me out so that i call my ansible to run from jenkins

Comment: <img src="https://www.clipular.com/posts/4650137218711552?k=OKjjzvpJyrE38N4ZOsuX2xppszM" width="100" height="100">

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the simple example, please ask in the comments if you need some specific help. Let's say, you job name is "`stackoverflow`" then you can put the `ansible-scripts` directory inside the `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/stackoverflow/workspace` and use it in your jenkins job like this:
[image]

After that you can use the shell environment:
[image]

Once you will configure this job then you can use it as you are normally using the ansible from the command line:
[image]
Please adjust the settings as per your environment.Hope this will help you

Comment: I have two more doubt here:
1. How you set the $WORKSPACE value
2. How to know my host-subset

Comment: 1 - by default, jenkins create the workspace under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/YOURJOBNAME/workspace and you can access it with $WORKSPACE. 2 - you can ignore the host-subset part if you want to run the tasks on all the hosts in the inventory file, here host-subset is repressing the --limit flag in ansible

Comment: I am getting below error under console ,after making changes to Jenkins.
<Snip>
+ export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=FALSE
+ ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=FALSE
+ export ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=TRUE
+ ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=TRUE
+ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-qa-frame-1
+ ansible-playbook -i ansile-scripts/hosts -path --extra-vars sudo=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 43, in <module>
    import ansible.constants as C
ImportError: No module named ansible.constants
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
</Snip>

Comment: can you please paste the screen shoot of your complete job in question and error screen.

Comment: Adding a screen shoot :--> [link](https://www.clipular.com/posts/4650137218711552?k=OKjjzvpJyrE38N4ZOsuX2xppszM)

Comment: Problem i can see is that when i run with uatuser i am able to run it ..
But when i am trying it with root user i am not able to do it ..
It seems Jenkins also running as root user ..
How should i resolve it and where should i try to look/fix for the issues..